# I want to create a compare function after onclick function and want to compare the tapped object to see if is eligable to proceed to next level

Tags: android, imagebutton

I want to compare the tapped objects in other functions and I have timer also if 5 seconds have gone the timer will be stoped and will display the tapped object in other activity

```
public class Play extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    final Context context = this;
    private MediaPlayer mplayer;
    private int counter = 0;
    // private TextView txt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    private int collectedapples = 0;
    int tappedapples = 0;
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private boolean timeHasStarted = false;
    private TextView text;
    public int colletedappels = 0;
    private final long startTime = 10 * 1000;
    private final long interval = 1 * 1000;

    // private ImageButton bt[];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play);
        text = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        countDownTimer = new MyCountDownTimer(startTime, interval);
        text.setText(text.getText() + String.valueOf(startTime / 1000));

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout1);
        rl.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background);

        // Ska skapa en activity till för att välja mellan tio äpplen//
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            ImageButton btn = new ImageButton(this);
            btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.apple);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            params.width = 83;
            params.height = 80;
            // Random ran = new Random();
            int left = (int) (Math.random() * 1024/2);
            int right = (int) (Math.random() * 600);

            if (left == 600 & right == 600) {
                params.setMargins(left, 10, right, 0);
            } else
                params.setMargins(left, 50, right, 0);
            // params.setMargins(left, top, right, bottom)
            // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT);
            // params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF,R.drawable.apple);
            // params.setMargins(10,12,50,0);
            // params.setMargins(0,20, 40, 0);
            // btn.setBackgroundColor(#f0f0f0);
            btn.setLayoutParams(params);
            rl.addView(btn);
            btn.setId(i);
            btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
    }

    public class MyCountDownTimer extends CountDownTimer {
        public MyCountDownTimer(long startTime, long interval) {
            super(startTime, interval);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Intent in = new Intent(Play.this, Done.class);
            startActivity(in);

        }

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            text.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // Display alert message when back button has been pressed
        backButtonHandler();
        return;
    }

    public void backButtonHandler() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertdialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Play.this);
        alertdialog.setTitle("Want to leave application");
        alertdialog.setMessage("Are you sure you want to quit?");
        alertdialog.setIcon(R.drawable.apple);
        alertdialog.setPositiveButton("YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }

                });
        alertdialog.setNegativeButton("NO",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        dialog.cancel();

                    }
                });
        alertdialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!timeHasStarted) {
            countDownTimer.start();
            timeHasStarted = true;
        }
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        colletedappels = tappedapples;
        tappedapples++;
        txt.setText("" + tappedapples);

        if (tappedapples == 5) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Intent in = new Intent(this,Done.class);
            in.putExtra("tappedapples",tappedapples);
            startActivity(in);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is working so far? What is not? 
Please provide a description of your concrete problem.

Comment: everthing is working perfect but i want to make a compare function to see if user have tapped objects as required and then the timer will stop.

Comment: What have you tried? I'm sure you'll understand that without a more detailed description of your problem it is impossible for us to actually help you. For instance, how are we supposed to know "what tapping the objects as required" means in this case?

Comment: I have built an application for children as read and learn game in which the user have to tapped on apples means objexts and then i want to make compare funtion to see user elgiable to proceed to next level.

Comment: User must collect more than 5 object to proceed to next level and tappedapples variable which will be found in OnClick function.